# CPU metrics in Grafana for Spring Webflux app with Actuator Micrometer and Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, spring-webflux, grafana, spring-boot-actuator, spring-micrometer

Small question on how to build visual and insight on CPU metrics please.

I have a Spring Boot Webflux app, nothing extraordinary.
I bring in the Actuator, Micrometer and Prometheus dependencies.

The app have out of the box metrics for CPU, which I think is very cool.
I also believe those metrics contains tremendous information.
Unfortunately, I believe not to understand Grafana or the metrics itself to fully unleash it potential.

The metrics are :

```
system_cpu_usage
process_cpu_usage
system_cpu_count
system_load_average_1m
```

Not knowing how to properly use them, I use those very basic noob queries:

```
system_cpu_usage{_ns_=“my_namespace",cluster=~”my_cluster"}
process_cpu_usage{_ns_=“my_namespace",cluster=~”my_cluster"}
system_cpu_count{_ns_=“my_namespace",cluster=~”my_cluster”}
system_load_average_1m{_ns_=“my_namespace",cluster=~”my_cluster"}
```

And with those, I do get some results back. The thing is, I get just some flat lines in which no further insights or action can be taken.

I see on the web some more complex queries, such as

```
avg_over_time(process_cpu_usage{_ns_=“my_namespace",cluster=~”my_cluster"}[1h])
```

Or some using `delta rate irate`. But not sure what are they here for.

What is the proper way to use those metrics and what is wrong with my current queries as there is a gap between now and meaningful metrics.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `avg_over_time` for the last `1h` is useful in case you want to make a rule for the alertmanager. Imagine a use case where every spike on the cpu will trigger the alertmanager rule. That is something undesirable. By the way, in this specific use case I would prefer to use `histogram_quantile` becase average can hide high values (just because it is an average). Some best practices with percentiles are here: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#quantiles . Then you use `rate` to determine the time window for your quantile.

```
histogram_quantile(0.9, rate(
  process_cpu_usage{_ns_=“my_namespace",cluster=~”my_cluster"}[1h]
))
```